# Once a paid app is purchased, can it be downloaded unlimited number of times?

Tags: paid-apps

Once I purchase an android app on the appstore, can I download it again and again in future (say I change devices or factory reset my phone)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. as long as its the same account.